# Return documents in query snapshot as json string firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query made in node to firestore to get a collection of document. I want to write the collection as a json string to be parsed by an application. My code is as follows:

```
serverRef = db.collection('servers');
        getDocs = serverRef.where('online', '==', true).get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                res.send("NO SERVERS AVAILABLE");
            } else {
                var docs = querySnapshot.docs;
                console.log('Document data:', docs);
                res.end(JSON.stringify({kind: 'freeforge#PublicServerSearchResponse',servers: docs}));
            }
```

I get unnecessary data this way as all I get is document snapshots. How do I loop through the document snapshots and send them in one json string?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `QuerySnapshot` and `Document` classes are not simple JSON types. If you want to control what is written, you'll need to loop over `querySnapshot` (with `map` or `forEach`) and extract the JSON data for yourself.

One possible example:

```
serverRef = db.collection('servers');
getDocs = serverRef.where('online', '==', true).get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        res.send("NO SERVERS AVAILABLE");
    } else {
        var docs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        console.log('Document data:', docs);
        res.end(JSON.stringify({kind: 'freeforge#PublicServerSearchResponse', servers: docs}));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking for flutter answer is this,

```
    serverRef = db.collection('servers');
    getDocs = serverRef.where('online', '==', true).get()
     .then(querySnapshot => {
       if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          res.send("NO SERVERS AVAILABLE");
          } else {
         var docs = 
         querySnapshot.docs.map(json.decode(json.encode(doc.data())));
       }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking for C#, the key is to transform the document into Dictionary first and then serialize into Json like this:

```
    var document = await FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance.Collection("collection_name").Document("document_id").GetSnapshotAsync();
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document.ToDictionary());
```

using the example from the question:

```
   var serverRef = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance.Collection("servers");
   var querySnapshot = await serverRef.WhereEqualTo("online", true).GetSnapshotAsync();
   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(querySnapshot.Documents.Select(o => o.ToDictionary()));
```