# Export firestore into a traditional json file

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to do something "old school", however I am not expert in Firebase or NodeJs so kinda need the help from the professionals.

this is my code.

```
exports.firest = functions.firestore
 .document('produkter/{produkterID}')
 .onUpdate((snap, context) => {
     const db = admin.firestore();
     const produkterRef = db.collection('produkter');
     return produkterRef.get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
         const orders = [];
         querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
             const order = doc.data();
             orders.push(order);
         });
         const json = JSON.stringify(orders);
         console.log(json)
         const blob = Buffer.from([json],{type:'application/json'});
          admin.storage().bucket('gs://aa.appspot.com').upload('produkter.json', {metadata: {blob}})
             admin.storage().bucket('gs://aa.appspot.com').put(blob).then(function(snapshot) {
             console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
         }) 
     });})
```

but this is producing error on the firebase functions console. Could someone help me with this?

this is the error:

```
TypeError: admin.storage(...).bucket(...).put is not a function
at produkterRef.get.then (/srv/index.js:56:72)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

best and kindest regards

Comment: Seems that what you are asking is very similar to [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924257/return-documents-in-query-snapshot-as-json-string-firestore), if not, can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: "but this is producing error on the firebase functions console." => Please edit your question to include the exact error message, and the complete stack trace. Also please study [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as you're using quite a few complex technologies in this question, and it's more likely someone can help if you can isolate the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you there is no method called `put()` on a [Bucket](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html) object.

If you have data in memory to upload, you should look into creating a [File](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html) object and using [save()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save) on it.

You are also not handling promises correctly, so you will run into other problems unless you do that.  Cloud Functions requires that you [terminate your functions properly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) by returning a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.